# Async/Await, Multiple Tasks (.NET 4.0/ NuGet Microsoft Async)

Tags: .net, winforms, asynchronous, .net-4.0, async-await

I'm limited to Microsoft Async NuGet package and so far I'm really liking the async/await syntax. I have many methods working smoothly with this technique, but I've run into a bit of problem trying to get a bit fancier.

I have a requirement to load multiple data sources, Inventories, Departments, etc. I would like the top level method to wait for all sources to load, and then carry on. The code seems to be deadlocking. I've done some research but I'm missing something in my understanding.

Here's the top level call:

```
await GlobalData.WaitAsync(GlobalData.DataType.Inventory | GlobalData.DataType.Departments).ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext: false);
```

The WaitAsync..

```
public static async Task<bool> WaitAsync(DataType flags)
{
    TaskCompletionSource<bool> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
    Task<bool> task = tcs.Task;

    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(_ =>
    {

        try
        {
            List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();

            foreach (DataType t in Enum.GetValues(typeof(DataType)))
            {
                if (t != DataType.None && flags.HasFlag(t))
                {
                    tasks.Add(GetModel(t).GetTask());
                }
            }

            /* Remove any tasks that are null. */
            tasks.RemoveAll(t => t == null);

            Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
            tcs.SetResult(true);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    });

    return await task;
```

And finally, inside GetTask(..)

```
public override Task GetTask()
{
    /* If the task is not null, another caller has asked for the data already, hook into the callback. */
    if (m_LoadingTask != null)
    {
        return m_LoadingTask;
    }
    else
    {
        /* Only load if the bindingList is null, return the Task. */
        if (m_Data == null)
        {
            return this.LoadAsync();
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

I can see the execution going through the code as expected. The Task.WaitAll(...) returns and executes tcs.SetResult(true), but never makes it back to the top level await.

What can I do to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why is your `WaitAsync` method an async method at all? You could just return `tcs.Task` from a synchronous method... an async method which ends with `return await ...` and doesn't have any other `await` expressions is always at least a *candidate* for refactoring. That's not the issue here, but it's something to think about. (Likewise any time you've got a catch block which is just `throw;`, consider removing it... the *only* benefit is being able to put a break point on it.)

Comment: Hi Jon, thanks for the expedient response. You are correct in your observations regarding my use of async/await. It seems I missed the point. I'll refactor using the TAP model and apply the aysnc/await only to my top level method. 

I'll post back with results.

Thanks!

Comment: To be clear, I wouldn't expect it to change the behaviour, just simplify the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use a `TaskCompletionSource` or `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` simply `await  Task.WhenAll(tasks.ToArray())` should do the trick.

```
public static async Task<bool> WaitAsync(DataType flags)
{
    List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();

    foreach (DataType t in Enum.GetValues(typeof(DataType)))
    {
      if (t != DataType.None && flags.HasFlag(t))
      {
          tasks.Add(GetModel(t).GetTask());
      }
    }

    /* Remove any tasks that are null. */
    tasks.RemoveAll(t => t == null);

    await TaskEx.WhenAll(tasks.ToArray());

    return true;
}
```

You deadlock likkely occurs because you used `Task.WaitAll`. `Task.WaitAll`, `Task.Wait` and `Task.Result` are blocking calls and can cause deadlock. See [this](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) article for more info.

For .Net 4.0 and Async CTP you can use `TaskEx.WhenAll`

Comment: Hi Ned, the Task.WhenAll(...) is not available in .NET4.0 with NuGet Microsoft Async. I wish it were!

Comment: For .Net 4.0 and Async CTP you can use `TaskEx.WhenAll`

Comment: Oh wow! You are right. I'll definitely be adding that to my repertoire. Sorry I missed that when I read it the first time around. As Jon Skeet said, I'm going to remove the return await, since it isn't necessary. Additionally I want the code to block my top level method.

I'll use both Jon's Wait and your WaitAsync. Thanks Ned!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to Jon Skeet for pointing me in the right direction. I removed async/await and found this code to be the solution:

```
public static bool Wait(DataType flags)
{
    List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();

    foreach (DataType t in Enum.GetValues(typeof(DataType)))
    {
        if (t != DataType.None && flags.HasFlag(t))
        {
            tasks.Add(GetModel(t).GetTask());
        }
    }

    /* Remove any tasks that are null. */
    tasks.RemoveAll(t => t == null);

    Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());

    return true;
}
```